# SAS 9.4 Outputting Plots to Wrong Destination

Tags: plot, directory, sas, output, png

I'm trying to output a probability plot that used to work in SAS 9.3, and now it is outputting in the wrong destination with a generic name. Using the code below, I should get a `.emf` probability plot titled `PROBPLOT (UNTRANS).emf` in the `GRAFOUT` destination. However, it's outputting the plot I want and naming it `ProbPlot1.png` in the destination where my SAS code is located `C:\Users\Name\Documents\Projects\Task 3\SAS Code` which is clearly not specified in the `GRAFOUT` statement. It's unbelievably frustrating and I'm not sure why it worked in 9.3 and not in 9.4 -- can anyone see the issue?

```
    ODS LISTING;
    GOPTIONS RESET=ALL RESET=GOPTIONS DEVICE=EMF NOPOLYGONFILL  FTEXT="ARIAL/BOLD"
         ROTATE=LANDSCAPE CTEXT=BLACK CSYMBOL=BLACK  CBACK=WHITE HTEXT=5 PCT
         DISPLAY NOPROMPT GSFMODE=REPLACE GSFNAME=GRAFOUT HSIZE=6IN VSIZE=3IN;

    FILENAME GRAFOUT "C:\Users\Name\Documents\Projects\Task 3\Results\Prob Plots\PROBPLOT (UNTRANS).EMF";
    PROC UNIVARIATE DATA=STD_RES NORMAL NOPRINT GOUT = GNEW1;
       VAR RESID;
       PROBPLOT RESID;
       INSET PNORMAL;
    QUIT;
```

Comment: Are you running this with `ODS GRAPHICS OFF`?  If you're running with `ODS GRAPHICS ON`, which should be default (in both 9.4 and 9.3), there are easier/better ways to do this.

Comment: Out of curiosity and always seeking simplicity, would you suggest @Joe?

Comment: Look at the ODS GRAPHICS options.  That was added in 9.2 (and made default in 9.3) to simplify a lot of this.  It does mean the graphs by default look somewhat different - you may or may not be able to get an exactly identical graph (though it should be a lot _better_ overall).  Largely it takes all of that GOPTIONS stuff and moves it to ODS GRAPIHCS, makes some better defaults, and makes the output files easier to manage.  (The answer you're using actually takes advantage of some of this - using the ODS dest to redirect the file - though that's now available to both methods.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a `filename` statement, which is creating a fileref called `grafout`. `grafout` is not being utilized anywhere since it occurs after the `goptions` statement, and is simply a variable pointing to the specified directory. Instead, use the `ODS PRINTER` statement:

```
ODS printer printer=emf 
file="C:\Users\Name\Documents\Projects\Task 3\Results\Prob Plots\PROBPLOT (UNTRANS).EMF";
```

This syntax is valid for any ODS output format. Make sure to add `ods printer close;` after you're done creating printed output.

Comment: Try doing the edited answer. I realized EMF is a very different file format than I originally thought. There's a different ODS option for `printer` as long as you have the `emf` driver installed.

Comment: You've now edited it back into consistency :) Thanks

Comment: Scratch that -- everything is fine! Thanks @Stu and of course Joe.